# SSMS - every SELECT statement creates extra empty line - how to suppress?

Tags: sql, ssms

If I set in SQL Management Studio to produce an output to Text (not to grid or to file) and run following:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT '1'
SELECT '2'
SELECT '1'
```

I get this:

```
1

2

1
```

How to remove extra new line after every line?
I set as default in Tools->Options following:
1. Output format as TAB delimited
2. Excluded column headers in the result set
3. Created a New Query

**UPDATE:**
Previous query is shown for sake of simplicity. Please take this one as a question:

```
SELECT 1+2
SELECT 'A FOX'
SELECT 1,2,3
```

Want to see no extra line between lines, e.g:

```
3
A FOX
1  2  3
```

Comment: @Oded - Thank you for UNION. I knew about it, but example I gave is simplified.

Comment: How does your update show that Oded's answer won't solve your problem? There are still 3 `SELECT` clauses, and so you will still get 3 distinct result sets, with an empty line in between each.

Comment: UNION ALL joins similar result sets only. On my updated statement, if I append UNION ALL I get this error:
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: @ilshat - I do not believe you can do this (not with a different number of columns anyway). Adding a new line is the default behavior for SELECT results. What is the reason you need to do this? Just wondering if there is a different solution.

Comment: did you find an answer to your problem? I have a similar issue.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting three separate result sets - one for each select.

In order to get a *single* result set (with duplicates) you need to `UNION ALL` the selects:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT '1' UNION ALL
SELECT '2' UNION ALL
SELECT '1'
```

See [UNION (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) on MSDN for details.

---

Update:

What you want to do is not possible. The types and numbers of the fields are different in each select - you can't `UNION` them.

You can't have a single result set that has different number of columns per row or with different data types per row.

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of posting comment, I decided to post answer, since it may help someone.
The output of the stored procedure I need to paste in Excel and apply "copy format" from template.
I resolved this problem this way:

Initial statement I have

```
SELECT 'Report Header'
SELECT ''
SELECT 'Line of report',1
SELECT 'Line of report',23
SELECT * FROM SUBREPORT
SELECT 'SUBTOTAL:',(select count(*) from another_table)
SELECT ''
SELECT 'REPORT GENERATED AT ', GetDate()
```

I updated to this:

```
SELECT 'Report Header'
SELECT '[NEWLINE]'
SELECT 'Line of report',1
SELECT 'Line of report',23
SELECT * FROM SUBREPORT
SELECT 'SUBTOTAL:',(select count(*) from another_table)
SELECT '[NEWLINE]'
SELECT 'REPORT GENERATED AT ', GetDate()
```

Since extra empty lines breaks formatting, I have to remove them.
I took the text output and pasted in Word.
Replaced "^p^p" with "^p", and then "[NEWLINE]" with "" (nothing).
Copy-Paste to Excel and copy format from template.
Done.

I would appreciate if someone can suggest more elegant solution.